# I am trying to get UserProfile using Django Simple JWT, however I get error "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got User."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I wanted to use email instead of username to login the user, so I obtained below code from the django documentation from custom authorization section.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, name, password=None, password2=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have an Email Address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        name = name
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, name, password=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        name=name,
        password=password
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

I have used custom user manager and added email field and name field. Name is required and authorization will be done using email of the user. I was able to create super user and login successfully. I was also able to register the user using REST endpoint. I want to try to login the user and view the profile. I was able to successfully login user and get access & refresh token using Simple JWT. But when I try to hit profile endipoint I get

> "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got User."
> Error

My view is as follows, I am using UserRenderer to get response in the required format, this works correctly for user registration and login endpoints and I dont think thats the issue here.:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@renderer_classes([UserRenderer])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def user_profile(request):
    print("DATA", request.user)
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.user)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response({"data":serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here print statement give me the email of the user trying to access the endpoint, I think it obtains it from the token passed.
And serializer I used is

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'email']
```

I am passing access token as Bearer token in header section of the endpoint
[image: End point where I try to access the profile view]

Comment: When serializing an object pass it using the keyword `instance` not `data` - `serializer = UserProfileSerializer(instance=request.user)`

Comment: @IainShelvington tried already, gives error `Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance`

Comment: Remove the call to `serializer.is_valid()`?

Comment: @IainShelvington this worked thank you friend. Can you explain it a bit, why data did not work but instance did, was serializer checking if object exists when passed as instance?

Comment: When you want to take some data (from an API call for example), validate and maybe save it you pass the data dict as `data=`. When you want to serialize an instance of your model you pass the object as `instance=`. When passing an instance it is not validated

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `request.user` inside serializer data, you should do:

```
serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
```